# How to fetch data from RESTAPI with react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

The data in the API looks like this:

```
[
  { "lon": "4,483792", "lat": "51,917029" },
  { "lon": "4,483792", "lat": "51,919029" },
  { "lon": "4,483892", "lat": "51,929029" },
  { "lon": "4,484892", "lat": "51,931029" },
  { "lon": "4,423892", "lat": "51,919400" },
  { "lon": "4,438892", "lat": "51,915322" },
  { "lon": "4,483092", "lat": "51,917500" },
  { "lon": "4,403892", "lat": "51,925029" }
]
```

How can i retrieve these data to my react app?

I have something like this right now (I know it's wrong):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test3 extends Component {
    state = {
        loading: true,
        coordinates: null,
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "https://ttr.vsbbn.nl:4000/gps_history?team_id=1";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ coordinates: lon, loading: false });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.loading || !this.state.coordinates ? (
                    <div>loading...</div>
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        <div>{this.state.lon}</div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Test3;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `coordinates: data`? Where's the `lon` from? Also there is no `this.state.lon` like you reference in your render function. I think your mixing up your property names

Comment: If `https://ttr.vsbbn.nl:4000/gps_history?team_id=1` returns that data then this should work:

const data = await response.json();
this.setState({coordinates: data, loading: false });

Comment: Yes and as @Jayce444 suggests, replace `this.state.lon` with `this.state.coordinates `

Comment: You are almost half of the way. Use `data` to set your state, and use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to render your items. Also, it is a good habit set the initial state to `[]` for `coordinates`.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got the good code ! As mentionned you need to set your state with the right data piece named `data` :

```
const data = await response.json();
this.setState({coordinates: data, loading: false });
```

Now you can iterate through your data with `map()` method

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test3 extends Component{
    state = {
        loading: true,
        coordinates: null,
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const url = "https://ttr.vsbbn.nl:4000/gps_history?team_id=1";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({coordinates: data, loading: false });

    }

    render(){
        const { loading, coordinates } = this.state
        return(
            <div>
                {loading || !coordinates ? (
                    <div>loading...</div>
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        {coordinates.map((coordinate, index) => {
                             return (
                               <div key={index}>
                                 <p>Longitute: {coordinate.lon}</p>
                                 <p>Latitude: {coordinate.lat}</p>
                               </div>
                             )
                         })}
                    </div>
                )}

            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Test3;
```

Comment: The crucial part is setting the right data piece here, namely `data`. It would be better if you mention this first. Also, in the mapping part, adding a proper `key`  (or mentioning this) would be nice.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback I've edited my answer, could you be more specific about "adding a proper `key`" part ?

Comment: Why the heck this answer downvoted? Thanks for the addition. Every array item [needs a key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). Even if you don't do this in your example, at least you should mention this, maybe as a comment in your code.

Comment: I was downvoted ? Of course I missed `key` prop ... Thank you for your feedback, really usefull

Comment: Thanks for all your answers so far. I almost understand the code. What does map()  do? And the index? What does that do?

Comment: `map()` iterate through each item inside your `coordinates` array. The second parameter `index` is the item position inside this array. And the `key` prop is a good practice in React when you use `map()` method you have to add a key.

Comment: But be aware, using `index` as a key is something we should avoid. [Further reading](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). If there is a unique value we should use it, if not somehow we should generate it.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use `map()` to fetch data from the array.

```
this.state.coordinates.map( (item, index) => {
   return <div>
             <h3>The first group {index}</h3>
             <li>lon: {item[index]['lon']</li>
             // Make same to all
          </div>
}
```